# Regular expression match NGINX url segments from $request_uri variable

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

hoping for some insight here on this redirection process

I am hoping to redirect all URL's EXCEPT ones that match the following.

https://www.something.com/about-us/foo/ (single page)
AND
https://www.something.com/foo/some-arbitrary-segment/ (many pages with this structure)

These are the only urls in the sitemap containing "foo", so I am trying to simply match that.

I first need to check one other conditional variable (I am checking user agents for mobile devices)- all pages except those containing "foo" should redirect to a new domain.

```
set $mobile_redirect NO;

if (someconditionaluseragentstuff = someconditionaluseragentstuff) {
set $mobile_redirect YES;
}

if ($request_uri ~ "foo") {
set $mobile_redirect NO;
}

if ($mobile_redirect = YES) {
rewrite ^ https://www.somemobiledomain.com$request_uri? redirect;
break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `location /` block is typically the fall-through that matches URIs that did not previously match another `location` block.  And use `0` and `1` to represent true/false for cleaner config files.

Rembember 301 is permanent redirect, 302 is temporary

```
set $mobile_redirect 0;

if ($http_user_agent ~ "netscape navigator") {
  set $mobile_redirect 1;
}

# Specific URIs /about-us/foo/ and /foo/*
location ~ ^/(about-us/foo/$|foo/)  {
  # Do nothing
}

# Every other URI
location / {
  if ($mobile_redirect) {
    return 301 https://website.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```